# I get a http errorcode 307 when trying to load Youtube Data api?

Tags: youtube-data-api, http-status-code-307

I try to load the Youtube data API (by injecting it in my header section).

It used to work out perfectly, but suddenly I only gets 307 response codes (and no real content).

307 is temporary_redirect, and this page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors

tells me to go fetch the content by forwarding the request to the location stated in the Location header of the 307 response. The thing is that there isn't anything in the Location header of the response! :-(

Does anyone know what is happening, how to fix it, and also how to prevent it from happening ever again? (should I create code to resend the request to a new URI when getting 307 responses??)

This is my injection code (but it used to work perfectly):

```js
var YTDtag = document.createElement('script'),
            YTItag = document.createElement('script');
        YTDtag.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=apiReady"; // load YouTube data API
        YTItag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"; // load YouTube Iframe API
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(YTDtag, firstScriptTag);
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(YTItag, firstScriptTag);
```

but the only response I get from https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=apiReady is the 307 number, and thus my apiReady never gets called.

If I try to load the page "manually" by putting it in a browser location field, it seems to load allright - but not when I try to load it through my js? :-/

Comment: What happens when you try to go to the script URL directly via your browser address bar?

Comment: Then I get the script, and it looks allright.

Comment: Check in developer tools, network panel, if the same redirect status code is send.

Comment: Just fetching the script directly via the locationbar seems completely straight forward. It returns the script with a 200 code (well 304 until I flushed the cache).

BTW: Now I am experiencing the same problem again. 307 codes and no locations in the location header of the response! :-( I can't live with not knowing when my videos are up and when they aren't. :-6

Comment: I have also tried to fetch it with curl, and there is no problem at all. Curl also just gets the script with a 200 code.

Comment: I have tried to not inject the script, but just include it in the header. That also gave me a 307 response.

I don't get the difference between putting a:
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
in the header of my page, and putting
https://apis.google.com/js/client.js
directly in the browsers locationbar (or fetching it with curl for that matter)?

Comment: That should make no difference, no. Do you have that problem only in your own browser/on your own machine, or others as well? Maybe any privacy plugins/extensions you got installed are interfering with it? If that’s not the case, and the problem is reproducible on other machines as well – then you might need to go and ask Google support for help.

Comment: The good news is that it works again now, the bad is I don't know why. I haven't done anything, and now it just works again. I do have the chrome extension Disconnect installed, and that might turn out to be the culprit, even though I think it shouldn't be. (thanks for remind me of extensions!). I should of course test it on other machines too, when the problem was there (why didn't I think of that myself?). Toss me an answer with the extension bit, and I will just call it the solution (I can't test if it really is right now, since the problem isn't occurring right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To narrow down this problem, check the following:

- Do you have that problem only in your own browser/on your own machine, or others as well?
- Maybe any privacy plugins/extensions you got installed are interfering with it?

If that’s not the case, and the problem is reproducible on other machines as well – then you might need to go and ask Google support for help.

---

(Added as an answer on OP’s request. Probably not *the* definite answer on this, but if this helped debug the issue or narrow it down, so be it … )

Comment: I suspect that it might be my Disconnect Chrome Extension, but the problem has not showed up again yet, so I will have to wait for it. It is a rather plausible cause though.

That also would explain why the problem suddenly appears, are consistent for a period, and as sudden disappears again. It might be because youtube has a commercial from a site I have blocked through Disconnect, and then the problem will go on until they change their commercial to a site I haven't blocked.

I will post a comment in here, if the problem emerges again, and I can test if it is because of Disconnect! :-)

Comment: It was Disconnect in Chrome for me